# Should I disable CSRF validation?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, csrf, csrf-protection

I am currently working on a application on Laravel which is a online quiz. There is a feature for resuming the user's session.

It means if the user reloads the page during the quiz his session is resumed with his filled responses. I use ajax to store users session each time he makes some changes in answers.

So, the problem is if user selects the answers fast enough to generate concurrent requests, Laravel terminates the user session so the CSRF token of the form becomes invalid.

To solve this issue I have disabled the CSRF validation for the ajax request as I think this request does not deal with any sensitive information of the website.

So I want to know that is it right to disable CSRF validation for such routes or I should find a different solution?

Comment: Why is Laravel terminating the session?  (Curious, as I haven't used Laravel.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Because there are too many requests from the same token I suppose as I haven't found a solid reason behind it so far. It is the only theory which satisfies the scenario.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth As I have read that it terminates the session in case of more then one concurrent requests from same user.

Comment: Did you implement it like this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/make-multiple-ajax-post-multiple-times?

Comment: Easiest way of fixing it and preserving CSRF protection is to save the data on moving to the next page. I really wouldn't save the data every time the user changes something. With a higher number of users you will crash your server and you're creating unnecessary traffic.

Comment: @walther I understand your point. But the whole intention of this is to save data for that page. If user reloads page without submitting. The submission of the form absolutely done at the page chnage.

Comment: @sebastian yes I have implemented it exactly like that.

Comment: Of course, that is how the internet works. If you want to prevent accidental reloads/misclicks, you can always popup a warning for them. Stackoverflow has the same thing - if you type a question/answer and then try to leave the page, it will ask you if you really want to do that.

Comment: I guess Laravel should not lock you out. Do I understand it right, that you only get problems if the users triggers to many ajax requests in a row?

Small idea: You could collect changes, and sent them from time to time, or when the user leaves the pages (onbeforeunload event)

Comment: @sebastian yes. That could be a good idea but actually quiz also have a clock so loosing results could be a problem.

Comment: @walther yes but UX is designed this way. We have considered many scenarios already but I will also have a look at that. It is a good approach though.

Comment: But actually what I want to know is it safe to remove csrf on such routes

Comment: I think the best approach here is to use something like an ajax queue plugin to ensure there's no overlap between requests.

Comment: @apokryfos Yes. I am also thinking of something like this because disabling the CSRF is something I have a bad feeling about.

Answer (score 0):

Why not creating an extra route just to pass a fresh token? so you could do a async query to fetch new token and then post it back to the laravel ?

like so:

```
/**
 * @Get("auth/csrfToken")
 */
public function getToken()
{
  return csrf_token();
}
```

Comment: this sounds like a very bad idea to me

Comment: Why ? can you motivate 'the sound' ...  if this route is behind auth guard ... only authenticated user could access it ... it is safer then removing the crsf protection